# Is There a Way to Hide a Default Initializer for Swift Struct?

Tags: struct, protocol-oriented

I have a protocol called `Parameter`:

```
protocol Parameter {

    var name: String { get }
    var unit: Unit? { get }
    var value: Double { get }

    init(name: String, unit: Unit?, value: Double)

}
```

I also have 16 structs that conform to `Parameter`:

```Swift
struct Calcium: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Calcium", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Alkalinity: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Alkalinity", unit: Unit? = Unit(symbol: "ppm CaCO3"), value: Double) {
        self.name = name
       self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

} 

struct Salinity: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Salinity", unit: Unit? = Unit(symbol: "SG"), value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

} 

struct Temperature: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Temperature", unit: Unit? = UnitTemperature.fahrenheit, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct PH: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "pH", unit: Unit? = nil, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Magnesium: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Magnesium", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Phosphate: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Phosphate", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Ammonia: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Ammonia", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Silica: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Silica", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Iodine: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Iodine", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Nitrate: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Nitrate", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Nitrite: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Nitrite", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Strontium: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Strontium", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct ORP: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "ORP", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct Boron: Parameter {

    var name: String
    var unit: Unit?
    var value: Double

    init(name: String = "Boron", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}

    struct Iron: Parameter {

        var name: String
        var unit: Unit?
        var value: Double

        init(name: String = "Iron", unit: Unit? = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: Double) {
            self.name = name
            self.unit = unit
            self.value = value
        }

    }
```

As you can see, all of the structs implement the same initializer. In the initializer, I provide default values for two of the three parameters required by the `Parameter` protocol, which gives me the following initializer:

```swift
let calcium = Calcium(value: Double)
```

I also get the default initializer created by the structs:

```swift
let calcium = Calcium(name: String, unit: Unit?, value: Double)
```

When I am creating instances of the structs, both initializers appear in Xcode's code completion popover. However, I don't want the `name` and `unit` parameters to be able to be anything different than the default values provided in the initializer. I have also tried assigning default values for the `name` and `unit` properties where the they are declared inside of the struct but outside of the initializer required by the `Parameter` protocol.

Is there a way to initialize the structs by providing default values for the `name` and `unit` parameters, requiring only the `value` parameter to be provided, while not having the default initializer show in Xcode's code completion popup?

The only concern that I have with having both initializers appear in Xcode's code completion popup is that I don't want someone else creating structs and providing values other than the ones that I have provided in the initializer required by the `Parameter` protocol.

I realize that I could do so with a class, but I am trying to get my mind right with protocol-oriented programming and using structs.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

We changed all variables to optionals, and removed initializer with default parameters from protocol. If `unit` and `value` are going to have default values *always*, there is no need for client to see this initializer.

```
protocol Parameter {
    var name: String? { get }
    var unit: Unit? { get }
    var value: Double? { get }
    //init(name: String, unit: Unit?, value: Double)
    init(value: Double)
}
```

And change structure to look like this:

```
struct Calcium: Parameter {

    var name: String? = nil
    var unit: Unit? = nil
    var value: Double? = nil

    init(value: Double) {
        self.init(name: "Calcium", unit: UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion, value: value)
    }

    private init(name: String, unit: Unit, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }

}
```

In structure itself, we have added private initializer, which is called from custom initializer requiring only one parameter.

And you will have only one initializer in Xcode completion popup.
[image]